# ERROR: "Resample() got an unexpected keyword argument 'how'"

Tags: python, configuration, pycharm, interpreter

**The Code**

`symbol_1_data = symbol_1_data.resample('5T', how=ohlc_dict, closed='left', label='left')`

**The Error**

> Resample() got an unexpected keyword argument 'how'

**Question**
'how' is the expected argument for the resample command (syntax below), so why does it give me this error? could this be a config issue?

```
DataFrame.resample(rule, how=None, axis=0, fill_method=None, closed=None, label=None, convention=’start’, kind=None, loffset=None, limit=None, base=0, on=None, level=None)
```

Comment: What pandas version are you using?

Comment: Downgrade to 0.24.2 and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, try:

```
symbol_1_data = symbol_1_data.resample('5T', closed='left', label='left').ohlc_dict()
```